# Delete everything except multiline pattern, in which the end is defined as 1 line after the first line

Tags: vim, edit

**I wish to delete everything that does not match a pattern**

*What I have tried:*

I do slash-forward-search on this regex pattern:

```
\d\+_.*\n.*
```

which matches two pairs of lines:

```
A
50
Y
Not allowed
According to registry coding
3_Tumour_ID                      ### match
Tumour identification            ### match
A
50
Y
Not allowed
According to registry coding
4_Day_DoB                        ### match
Day of birth                     ### match
F
2
```

Then i try to delete everything but these matches using this:

```
:v//d
```

I get this:

```
3_Tumour_ID
4_Day_DoB
```

But I was expecting this:

```
3_Tumour_ID
Tumour identification
4_Day_DoB
Day of birth
```

Which is correct because it keeps all the matched lines, not just the first line of each match.

The second line I want to match (in each pair of lines I wish to match) is matched solely on the premise that it immediately succeeds the first line in each pair.

Comment: I copied your text in buffer, and did exactly same search, the `Tumour...` line and `Day of...` line are not matched.

Comment: yes, thanks, I fixed it now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you cannot use `:v//del comd` to do it. Because your search pattern contains new line, however `:g, :v` will do line based processing.  Therefore the `Tumour...` and `Day of...` lines will be processed by `:v` again, finally removed.

What you can try is:

```
qaq    (to clear "a register)
:g//norm! "A2Y   (this copy all matched lines into register a)
ggVG"ap
```

Note: I used `2Y` because you have one `\n` in your pattern, that is, your matched result will always be two lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the following regexes:

```
:%g!/Tumour\|Day/d
```

Negative Global command `g!`

```
:%s/\(^.*Tumour.*\n\|^.*Day.*\n\)\zs\|.*\n//g
```

Or this quite complex substitution